# Why does my action cause the props to change?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component that displays post received and another that displays post that users posted, My action grabs the post depending on which tab they click. Below are the actions.

```
import {  FETCH_POSTS_RECEIVED  } from './types';



export const fetchPostReceived = (id) => dispatch => {
    fetch('/posts/vh5given/' + id , {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'content-type' : 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(userPosts => dispatch ({
        type:FETCH_POSTS_RECEIVED,
        payload: userPosts
    }));
    // .then(data = console.log(data));
  }

export const fetchPostsFromUser = (id) => dispatch => {
  fetch('/posts/' + id , {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
          'content-type' : 'application/json'
      }
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(posts => dispatch ({
      type:FETCH_POSTS_FROM_USER,
      payload: posts
  }));
  // .then(data = console.log(data));
}
```

They function is called on ComponentDidUpdate

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // console.log(prevUserId);
    let prevUserId = prevProps.user.map((user) => (user.id));
    let userId = this.props.user.map((user) => (user.id));
    if(prevUserId.length < 1 || prevUserId == undefined && userId) {
      console.log("Currently Updating from vh5");
      console.log(prevUserId);
      console.log(userId);
    this.props.fetchPostReceived(userId);
    }
  }

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // console.log(prevUserId);
  let prevUserId = prevProps.user.map((user) => (user.id));
  let userId = this.props.user.map((user) => (user.id));

  if(prevUserId.length < 1 || prevUserId == undefined){console.log('undefineeeeed')}
  if(prevUserId.length < 1 || prevUserId == undefined && userId) {
    console.log("Currently Updating");
    console.log(prevUserId);
    console.log(userId);
    this.props.fetchPostsFromUser(userId);

    console.log('this is the props ' + this.props.posts)
  }
}
```

The issue I am having is that the props get changed when the Fetch Post Received function is called. Because I am rendering the posts from the props state when it updates, the wrong post are displayed. 
[image]

[image]

Why is this happening and how can i fix it?

Comment: Why do you have 2 componentDidUpdate?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the issue is most likely in the reducer (if state is being changed which you don't expect). Can you show the reducer?

Comment: Sorry if im not clear but its two different components

Comment: Wow thanks james, I had the FETCH_POST_RECEIVED in another reducer so it was there twice. Thanks!

Comment: I think there might be some issue with the reducer. May be you're not mutating your objects in an immutable pattern. But also there's one confusion that you mentioned props get changed. What exactly do you mean by saying this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment, but are you calling componentDidMount twice (this is what your code suggests), or are those two seperate things you have tried, because

```
  let prevUserId = prevProps.user.map((user) => (user.id));
  let userId = this.props.user.map((user) => (user.id));
```

or

```
    this.props.fetchPostsFromUser(userId);
```

firing twice could be your issue.